# I am unable to use np.concatenate

Tags: python, data-science, linear-regression, np

I have 2 variables from polynomial regression:

```
y_test = [1.57325397 0.72686416]
y_pred= [1.57325397 0.72686416]
```

`y_test` is the y axis of the test i did, while `y_pred` is are the values i got from `regressor.predict` (`regressor` is the object of `LinearRegression` class).

I tried to use `np.concatenate((y_test),(y_predict))` but it did not work and it said only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. So what should I do here? it OK to round of the values to integers or should I do something else?

Comment: `np.concatenate((y_test, y_pred))`?

Answer (score 1):

You should first separate your list values with a comma:

```
y_test = [1.57325397,0.72686416]
y_pred= [1.57325397,0.72686416]
```

For concatenation you should define an axis and use following syntax:

```
np.concatenate((y_test, y_pred), axis=0)
```

Then you would get

```
array([1.57325397, 0.72686416, 1.57325397, 0.72686416])
```